# Andengine MotionStreakExample and screenshots

Tags: android, screenshot, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

I want to capture the screen by rendering scene into the RenderTexture, i've tried to do this in [MotionStreakExample](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/MotionStreakExample.java) and everything is ok, but when i copy code to my project i have this picture (maybe there are some troubles with textures... i can't understand):
[image]

```
@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine(EngineOptions pEngineOptions) {
    return new Engine(pEngineOptions) {

        private boolean mRenderTextureInitialized;

        private RenderTexture mRenderTextures ;
        private Sprite mRenderTextureSprites ;

        @Override
        public void onDrawFrame(final GLState pGLState) throws InterruptedException {
            final boolean firstFrame = !this.mRenderTextureInitialized;

            if(firstFrame) {
                this.initRenderTextures(pGLState);
                this.mRenderTextureInitialized = true;
            }

            final int surfaceWidth = WIDTH*2;
            final int surfaceHeight = HEIGHT;


            this.mRenderTextures.begin(pGLState, false, true);
            {
                /* Draw current frame. */
                super.onDrawFrame(pGLState);

                /* Draw previous frame with reduced alpha. */
            }
            this.mRenderTextures.end(pGLState);


            {
                pGLState.pushProjectionGLMatrix();
                pGLState.orthoProjectionGLMatrixf(0, surfaceWidth, 0, surfaceHeight, -1, 1);
                {
                    this.mRenderTextureSprites.setAlpha(1);
                    this.mRenderTextureSprites.onDraw(pGLState, this.mCamera);
                }
                pGLState.popProjectionGLMatrix();
            }

            if (needToSave)
            {
                needToSave = false;
                FSHelper.saveBitmapToFile(this.mRenderTextures.getBitmap(pGLState), SAVED_PATH+"/test.png");
            }

            /* Flip RenderTextures. */

        }

        private void initRenderTextures(final GLState pGLState) {
            final int surfaceWidth = WIDTH*2;
            final int surfaceHeight = HEIGHT;

            final VertexBufferObjectManager vertexBufferObjectManager = mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager();
                this.mRenderTextures = new RenderTexture(mEngine.getTextureManager(), surfaceWidth, surfaceHeight);
                this.mRenderTextures.init(pGLState);

                final ITextureRegion renderTextureATextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(this.mRenderTextures);
                this.mRenderTextureSprites = new Sprite(0, 0, renderTextureATextureRegion, vertexBufferObjectManager);
        }
    };
}
```

PS. this cross with red background is a sprite on my scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer !
Textures are loaded dynamicly and on the first frame i haven't load textures at all, because i have a choose dialog there and create all textures after it. I need to call initRenderTextures each time when textures are changed.

Comment: Make sure you destroy the old ones!

Answer (score 1):

Andengine already has an infrastructure for taking screenshots, have you tried using that? Take a look at the example:
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/ScreenCaptureExample.java

Comment: i know about this feature (and use it now instead of described method), but maximum resolution of this screenshot is DEVICE.WIDHTxDEVICE.HEIGHT and i want a bigger one =)

Comment: Maybe you could modify AndEngine's ScreenGrabber to suit your needs. Anyway, I took a closer look at the image you provided and at the code and I think I might know what's wrong. It seems you are taking the very first frame, right? The colorful mess looks like a random snapshot of memory and I have seen some indications that the textures in AndEngine are loaded asynchronously. Maybe you take the screenshot too early, before the images have completely loaded. Try giving the engine a couple of hundreds of milliseconds before taking the screenshot.

Comment: the screenshot that i've provided is not exactly this screenshot, it has been taken with ddms (where scene need to be drawn). I see this all time. If i comment renderTextureBegin.start and  renderTextureBegin.end everything is ok (on scene), but i have no rendertexture to save. When i press save button i perfrom "needToSave = true" and the taken screenshot is empty. With begin end and drawframe betwee them i can't see my scene, only this random pixels

Comment: and ScreenGrabber as i see only walk through all pixels in RenderSurface and save it's color. I have to draw whole scene in virtual texture (with custom size) and then save it.